# Unsigned Integer Comparison

Tags: java

I was assuming that "compareUnsigned" in the below example will return 0. But it is returning -1. Why is b treated as greater than a?

```
    int a = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int b = Integer.MAX_VALUE * -1;

    System.out.printf("x compared to y: %d%n", Integer.compare(a, b));
    System.out.printf("x compared to y: %d%n", Integer.compareUnsigned(a, b));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`compareUnsigned` does not do what you think it does. You probably thought it compares the *magnitudes* of the arguments only, without considering their signs. However, what it really does is that it treats the two ints as a `uint` (which doesn't really exist in Java, which is why this method exists!).

Maybe the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compareUnsigned-int-int-) isn't really clear on this, it just says "treating the values as unsigned." which could be interpreted as "ignoring the signs", but if you look at the implementation of `compareUnsigned`, you'll see what it actually does:

```
public static int compareUnsigned(int x, int y) {
    return compare(x + MIN_VALUE, y + MIN_VALUE);
}
```

Anyway, to compare two `uint`s, we just have to look at their binary representation. `MAX_VALUE` in binary is 31 ones (let's ignore leading zeros), whereas the negation of it is 1 one followed by 30 zeros, followed by 1 one.

```
1111111111111111111111111111111 // MAX_VALUE
10000000000000000000000000000001 // -MAX_VALUE
```

It is clear which is bigger as an unsigned binary number. It's obviously the one that has more digits.

---

To actually compare the two integers without considering the signs, apply `Math.abs` then compare (won't work for `Integer.MIN_VALUE` though, you'd have to check that separately):

```
Integer.compare(Math.abs(a), Math.abs(b))
```

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper! What is the use case that this operation helps solve? I believe it doesn't help save memory as the underlying int primitive is still unsigned.

Comment: @PunterVicky well, for example, you might want a field to “pretend” to be a `uint` in other languages, having twice the positive range of `int` but taking up the same 4 bytes.

Comment: How does pretending a field to be uint help since I assume max value that a long or int can hold is still the same?

Comment: @PunterVicky No, a normal `int` covers the range `-2147483648` = `0x80000000` (`Integer.MIN_VALUE`) to `2147483647` = `0x7fffffff` (`Integer.MAX_VALUE`). A `uint` covers the range `0` to `4294967295` = `0xffffffff`.

Comment: @PunterVicky If you're reading or writing a data structure that has a 4-byte `uint` value, e.g. a file header, then using a Java two's complement `int` to process the value can cause problems, especially if you compare values like the question does. In these cases, the comparison must be done "unsigned", as if the value in the `int` is not in two's complement.

Comment: @Sweeper `Integer.compare(Math.abs(a), Math.abs(b))` doesn't work if one of the two values are `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, since, as the javadoc of [`Math.abs()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#abs(int)) says it: *"if the argument is equal to the value of `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, the most negative representable `int` value, the result is that same value, which is negative"*.

Comment: @Andreas True, is there a way to elegantly handle that case? I think you just have to hardcode it in, right?

Comment: @Andreas thank you. But in Java I was assuming the underlying primitive integer is always signed and the comparison methods were added only to the Integer and Long objects. How can one store the max unsigned value in Java?

Comment: @PunterVicky You just store the int `-1`. And use `Integer.compareUnsigned` to compare it. `compareUnsigned` will tell you that it is positive (> 0) and bigger than any other integer. This is what I mean by "pretend to be a `uint`".

Comment: @PunterVicky The the underlying primitive `int` is a 4-byte binary value that is interpreted as a signed value in [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) by Java operators and methods, unless otherwise stated. To treat an `int` as unsigned, use the `xxxUnsigned` methods of [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#method.summary): `toUnsignedString`, `parseUnsignedInt`, `divideUnsigned`, `remainderUnsigned`, `compareUnsigned`, and `toUnsignedLong`.